# How to fix error: init(boundsSize:requestHandler:)’ is only available on iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I have this error: `’init(boundsSize:requestHandler:)’ is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer`

in my code

```
let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")!
    let albumArtwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
        return image
    })
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Because that is available only iOS 10.x  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191452/mpmediaitemartwork-initimage-deprecated-in-ios-10-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    albumArtwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
        return image
    })
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    albumArtwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
}
```

If you want to make app compatible to OS versions prior to iOS 10. Else you can just set Deployment target to new iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Because this is available on 10.0 and higher version of ios.
[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitemartwork/1649704-initwithboundssize)

**Solution 1**

```
let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")!
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            _ = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
                return image
            })
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            // code for lower then ios 10
            _ = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(image: image)
        }
```

**Solution 2**

Change Deployment target to **9.0 to 10.0**

[image]

Comment: What code should I write in `// code for lower then ios 10`?

Comment: add this:    _ = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(image: image)